# getting parameter information from FunctionDecl class in clang

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

How to get parameter information as a string from FunctionDecl class in clang . I'm trying but getting confused by so many inheritances. Also they compiler is saying that getReturnType() is not a member of FunctionDecl but doxygen documentation says otherwise . Please help.
http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html

```
using namespace std;
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace llvm;

.......
class ExampleVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<ExampleVisitor> 
{
    ......
    virtual bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *func) 
    {
            numFunctions++;
            string funcName = func->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString();
            string retName = func->getReturnType().getAsString();
            ...
            return true;
    }

}
```

Errors:-

> ‘class clang::FunctionDecl’ has no member named ‘getReturnType’

Comment: Show your code and the errors you get.

Comment: question is edited with code

Comment: Assuming the documentation is correct: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html#a04fff4dba009b06065d218036092ebbb

Where's that error coming from? Are you sure it's from that line? Can you try to fully qualify it with clang::FunctionDecl ?

Comment: qualifying didn't help and the error is from that line only

Comment: That's weird, please go and check Decl.h for getReturnType(). If you don't have it you might have to update your clang sources

Comment: **Please search for "getReturnType" inside Decl.h**

Comment: Yeah its not defined in Decl.h. I downloaded the source code from github as svn server was not working.Thanks .

Comment: o.k. sure. How to accept your answer ? I'm new to stack-overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending if you need a qualified or unqualified name, you can stringify your return type and parameter names as follows

```
std::string retType = F->getReturnType().getAsString();
std::string arg0;
if(F->getNumParams() > 0)
  arg0 = F->parameters()[0]->getQualifiedNameAsString();
```

Check out the [getAsString()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html#af755c58826e02f164c9b1d442762457d) method provided.

---

Edit: after your comments I figured out that you don't have the latest Clang source code. Please check it out before retrying. Good luck!

Comment: Then why is it saying that getReturnType() is not a member of FunctionDecl.

Comment: Either that error is coming from somewhere else or you're getting the wrong FunctionDecl - GitHub repository mirror (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/AST/Decl.h)

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
getResultType()
```

rather than

```
getReturnType()
```

llvm 3.4 has no member `getReturnType()` but identical function whose name is `getResultType()` exists.

Answer (score 0):

To get all parameter list dynamically, below code would help.

```
string retName = func->getReturnType().getAsString();
for(int i=0; i<func->getNumParams(); i++)
{
    std::cout << " " << func->parameters()[i]->getQualifiedNameAsString();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working function to print all the information about a  FunctionDecl.Tested on Windows/LLVM6.0.0

```
void printFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl* f) 
{
    std::cout << "FunctionDecl@:"<<f<<":"
        << f->getReturnType().getAsString()<<" "
        << f->getQualifiedNameAsString()
        <<"(";

    for (int i = 0; i < f->getNumParams(); i++)
    {
        if (i > 0) std::cout << ",";             
        std::cout 
            << QualType::getAsString(f->parameters()[i]->getType().split()
                , PrintingPolicy{ {} })<<" "
            << f->parameters()[i]->getQualifiedNameAsString();          
    }

    std::cout << ")"
        <<"   Definition@"<<f->getDefinition()
        <<"\n";
}
```